# Can I conditionally disable an NSMenuItem that is only enabled when the first responder responds to a selector?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I have an `NSMenuItem` that is enabled/disabled based on whether or not the first responder responds to a specific selector.

My problem is that there are conditions in which I do **not** want the item enabled for the first responder.

But I can't just conditionally remove a method definition during runtime to disable the menu item

**For an example of what I mean:**
I have a `NSDocument`-based application, and I have two main subclasses-- an `ImageDocument` and a `VideoDocument`

I have an `NSMenuItem` called "Capture Frame", which turns a frame of a video into an image.  But obviously this should be disabled on an `ImageDocument`, and only enabled on a `VideoDocument`.

The `NSMenuItem` is enabled if the first responder responds to `-captureFrame`

The `VideoDocumentController` has a method, `-captureFrame`, so it's enabled.
The `ImageDocumentController` does not, so the menu item is never enabled.

**But**, there are specific `VideoDocument`s that I do not want to have that menu item enabled for.  What could be the best way for me to disable this menu item in order to handle special cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `VideoDocument` class, override the `NSDocument` method `validateUserInterfaceItem:`.  Alternatively, you can override `validateUserInterfaceItem:` in a subclass of `NSDocumentController`.  Be sure to call `super` to keep the built-in functionality of this method.  See [Apple's docs on UI validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UIValidation/UIValidation.html) for an example.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks!  Your answer is actually a little off, I had to use `-validateMenuItem` on the controller of the document, and I also got an exception when I called `super`, so I didn't do that.  And then everything worked :D  Could you maybe edit your answer before I mark correct?

Comment: I added the possibility of overriding in NSDocumentController.  But if it didn't work, you did something wrong.  The docs on NSDocumentController even say you should call `[super validateUserInterfaceItem: ]` in the override.

Comment: Ah I see the issue, I said `VideoDocumentController`, not realizing that it implied I had a subclass of `NSDocumentController`.  My "controller" in this case is a subclass of `NSViewController` that displays the `VideoDocument`